# Daterangepicker - Change End date only. But, present default plugin not allows

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Using daterangepicker plugin for this booking. Additional requirement needed for improvement.

1. Used below script to load 'Select departure date' on click input date field. But, once user clicked 'start' date. Have to change text to 'Select return date'.
2. With current behaviour of plugin, return date is not changable. Have to change both start & end date. Is it possible to change only 'end' date if user mistakenly selected wrong date? no changes in 'start' date until user changes.

**HTML:**

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="returnTripDepart" name="ReturnTrip" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('#returnTripDepart').click(function(){
  $('.daterangepicker').addClass('returnTripDatePicker');
  $('.departure--date').hide();
  $(".returnTripDatePicker").prepend("<div class='departure--date'>Select Departure Date</div>");
});

var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var maxLimitDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear() + 1, nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('input[name="ReturnTrip"]').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": true,
    "autoUpdateInput": false,
    "minDate": today,
    "maxDate": maxLimitDate,
    "locale": {
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
    }
  },function(start:any, end:any) {
        $("#returnTripDepart").val(start.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
        $("#returnTripReturn").val(end.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
  });
```